# How do I scale a Spine animation at runtime?

Tags: sfml, spine

The spine docummentation shows how to scale the skeleton when loading. 
Is it a must to reload the skeleton to scale the animation while playing it?

Comment: Do you mean scale it as part of the animation data, or procedurally when rendering it in your game?

Comment: I need to do is procedurally, since my character moves in a virtual z axis in my 2d game and I need to make it smaller or bigger.

Comment: Which runtime are you using?

Comment: I'm using SFML library

Comment: SFML doesn't have built-in support for skeletal animation, is it possible you're using [this project](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=10624.0)?

Comment: I'm using spine SFML runtime https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/spine-runtimes/tree/master/spine-sfml

Comment: If you have everything below a root bone, you can just scale the root bone. All child bones and gfx are scaled with it.

Comment: I'd like to do that, but how?

Answer (score 1):

This is done by manipulating the bone directly, as in this documentation:
http://esotericsoftware.com/spine-using-runtimes#Manipulating-bones

The key here is that you have to perform the operation after calling AnimationState_update/apply but *before* calling Skeleton_updateWorldTransform:

```
Skeleton_update(spine->_Skeleton, dt);
AnimationState_update(spine->_AnimationState, dt);
AnimationState_apply(spine->_AnimationState, spine->_Skeleton);

// Now that the animation has applied any changes, provide our own manipulations:
spine->_Skeleton->x = transform->position.x;
spine->_Skeleton->y = transform->position.y;
spine->_Skeleton->root->scaleX = 0.5f;
spine->_Skeleton->root->scaleY = 0.5f;

spine->_Skeleton->root->rotation = 45.0f;

Skeleton_updateWorldTransform(spine->_Skeleton);
```